# How to Get Temporary Objects of Inactive Users in SE80

Tags: abap

We are in the process of migrating to Latest S/4HANA and we want to cleanup all the `$TMP` objects belonging to Inactive Users. We tried searching in `SE80` (tried Inactive Objects drop down option too) but we couldn't get the Enhancement, BADI, Implicit Enhancements (R3TR ENHO), Spots (R3TR ENHS), etc.

[image]

Following are the objects which we fetched manually:

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: "Inactive object" does not mean "object belonging to an inactive user" or "object that is not actively used by any functionality in the system".  It just means an object that was saved but not activated after the last time it was saved. Do you already have a list of the users you consider inactive?

Comment: @Philipp : "object belonging to an inactive user" - This is Correct. Objects are Active but User left Org and his/her ID became Inactive, But when we tried to search in SE80 for such user, no objects are displaying, but when viewed in particular t-code it is getting view, why we want in SE80 ?, because want to delete them in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one shot option in SE80 workbench to display/delete repository objects of deleted( inactive??) users.

Simpler option would be to write a custom report to get repository objects of such users, and delete those objects manually if the objects are not very large or write a BDC report to do the same.

Below is the sample code to fetch implicit enhancements of deleted users and delete them programmatically using BDC and CALL TRANSACTION.

The same can be extended for other object types or transactions using BDC recording.

```
REPORT z_repository_obj_del.

TABLES tadir.

SELECT-OPTIONS s_pgmid FOR tadir-pgmid DEFAULT 'R3TR'.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_obj FOR tadir-object DEFAULT 'ENHO'.
SELECT-OPTIONS s_objnm FOR tadir-obj_name .

CLASS lcl_rep_obj DEFINITION.

  PUBLIC SECTION.

    TYPES BEGIN OF ty_obj.
    TYPES pgmid TYPE  pgmid.
    TYPES object  TYPE trobjtype.
    TYPES  obj_name TYPE sobj_name.
    TYPES END OF ty_obj.

    DATA gt_obj TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_obj WITH EMPTY KEY.

    METHODS main.
    METHODS call_se20.
    METHODS fetch_data.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_rep_obj IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD fetch_data.

    SELECT FROM tadir
      FIELDS pgmid, object, obj_name
      WHERE
      pgmid IN @s_pgmid
      AND object IN @s_obj
      AND obj_name IN @s_objnm
      AND devclass = '$TMP'
      AND author NOT IN ( SELECT bname FROM usr01 ) "Local objects of users not in USR01 table aka deleted users
    INTO TABLE @gt_obj.

    IF gt_obj IS INITIAL.
      MESSAGE 'no data found' TYPE 'S'.
    ENDIF.

  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD call_se20.

    DATA ls_bdc_options TYPE ctu_params.
    DATA lv_subrc       TYPE sy-subrc.
    DATA lt_messages    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bdcmsgcoll.
    DATA ls_msg TYPE bdcmsgcoll.
    DATA lt_bdcdata     TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bdcdata.

* The coding was originally generated with the Batch Input Data Recorder -> transaction SM35/SHDB
* and then converted to the new VALUE # approach

    LOOP AT gt_obj ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_obj>).

      lt_bdcdata = VALUE #(

                           ( program = 'SAPLSPO4' dynpro = '0300' dynbegin = abap_true )

                           ( program = 'SAPLENHANCEMENTS' dynpro = '0100' dynbegin = abap_true )
                           ( fnam    = 'BDC_CURSOR'       fval = 'RSEUX-CXH_VALUE' )
                           ( fnam    = 'BDC_OKCODE'       fval = '/00' )
                           ( fnam    = 'RSEUX-C_XS'       fval = '' )
                           ( fnam    = 'RSEUX-CXH'        fval = 'X' )
                           ( fnam    = 'RSEUX-CXH_VALUE'  fval = <ls_obj>-obj_name )

                           ( program = 'SAPLENHANCEMENTS' dynpro = '0100' dynbegin = abap_true )
                           ( fnam    = 'BDC_CURSOR'       fval = 'RSEUX-CXH_VALUE' )
                           ( fnam    = 'BDC_OKCODE'       fval = '=DELETE' )
                           ( fnam    = 'RSEUX-CXH'        fval = 'X' )
                           ( fnam    = 'RSEUX-CXH_VALUE'  fval = <ls_obj>-obj_name )

                           ( program = 'SAPLSPO4'         dynpro = '0300' dynbegin = abap_true )
                           ( fnam    = 'BDC_CURSOR'       fval = 'SVALD-VALUE(01)' )
                           ( fnam    = 'BDC_OKCODE'       fval = '=FURT' )

                         ).

      DATA(lv_updmode) =  'L'. "local update task
      DATA(lv_dismode) =  'N'. "no screen display - everything in the background

      ls_bdc_options = VALUE #( updmode  = lv_updmode
                                dismode  = lv_dismode
                                defsize  = abap_false
                                racommit = abap_true
                                nobinpt  = abap_true
                                nobiend  = abap_true ).

      CALL TRANSACTION 'SE20' WITH AUTHORITY-CHECK USING lt_bdcdata
                       MESSAGES INTO lt_messages
                       OPTIONS  FROM ls_bdc_options.

      TRY.
          ls_msg = lt_messages[ msgid = 'SEEF_BASE' msgnr = '111' ].

          WRITE: / 'The following Enhancement successfully deleted:'(001) COLOR COL_HEADING,
                /  <ls_obj>-obj_name        COLOR COL_POSITIVE INTENSIFIED OFF ##NO_TEXT.

        CATCH cx_root.
          WRITE: / 'The following Enhancement could NOT be deleted:'(002) COLOR COL_HEADING,
                 /  <ls_obj>-obj_name        COLOR COL_NEGATIVE INTENSIFIED OFF ##NO_TEXT.
      ENDTRY.

      ULINE.

    ENDLOOP.

  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD main.

    TRY.
        fetch_data( ).
        call_se20( ).

      CATCH cx_t100_msg.
        RETURN.
    ENDTRY.

  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  DATA lo_rep_obj TYPE REF TO lcl_rep_obj .
  lo_rep_obj = NEW #( ).
  lo_rep_obj->main( ).
```

Comment: This is Excellent Satish. Tx a Ton.

Answer (score 0):

There must a bug in your system, no issue in a 7.40 system:

[image: SE80 inactive objects of deleted/inactive user]

Comment: We have 7.5 version, not able to see it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the screenshot about what you exactly see.

Comment: Updated with Screenshot. Thank you.